# Circular progress indicator not showing while using future builder

Tags: flutter, future

I am a noobi in flutter.i was tryin to show circular progress on loading data from an api on a button click. i am getting the response from the api. but i am its not entering inside future builder's snapshot condotions...

```
_onPressed(){
  setState(() {
  _textCCodeValues=myCCodeController.text;
  _textPhoneNumberValues=myPhoneNumberController.text;
  _textPasswordValues=myPasswordController.text;
  log("mobile",name: _textCCodeValues+" "+_textPhoneNumberValues);
  log("Password",name: _textPasswordValues);
  requestMap={
    'ccode':_textCCodeValues,
    'mobile':_textPhoneNumberValues,
    'password':_textPasswordValues,
    'app_Version':"1.1",
  };
  //_isOtpFieldVisible =!_isOtpFieldVisible;
  requestJson=json.encode(requestMap);
  //StringWidget(future: makeLoginRequest(requestJson));

  //makeLoginRequest(requestJson);

});
FutureBuilder(
  future: makeLoginRequest(requestJson),
  builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    _logData(snapshot.connectionState.toString());
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      _logData("in waiting");
      return SpinKitRotatingCircle(
        color: Colors.blue,
        size: 50.0,
      );
    }
    return null;
  },

);
```

}

the future that i am using is

```
Future<String> makeLoginRequest(String requestJson) async{
 final uri = url;

 final headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
"Accept": "application/json",
};

var response=await post(
uri,
headers:headers,
body: requestJson,
);
print("${response.body}");
return response.toString();

}
```

I dont know what went wrong. please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing your code like,

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: makeLoginRequest(requestJson),
  builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text("Data");
    } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("Error");
    } else {
        return SpinKitRotatingCircle(
        color: Colors.blue,
        size: 50.0,
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: @MaheshKumar are you able to login ? the circular progress bar might now be shown if the requested data is getting fetched too soo. You can add some delay before making API call.